# How can I hook up an async event handler to a non async event in WinRT?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a page derived from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page and I want to do something like so:

```
Loaded += OnPageLoaded;
```

where:

```
private async Task OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   await SomeAsync();
}
```

Is it even possible to hook this up?

I get:

```
error CS0407: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task 
    MyApp.MyPage.OnPageLoaded(object, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs)' 
    has the wrong return type
```

Msdn alludes to something like this at [Events and routed events overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758286.aspx), but haven't been able to get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, an asynchronous task should return a `Task` or `Task<T>`.  In this case, though, it is perfectly acceptable for it to return `void`.  Your method signature should be

```
private async void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: To elaborate, `async void` is acceptable in this case *because it's an event handler*.

Comment: Thanks to the editrors for cleaning up my poor formatting/lack of attention to detail.  Yes, if you want to see the full explanation of how async/await works, and in doing so have an explanation of why returning void is acceptable in an event handler, see this video. http://bit.ly/1djOAiP