# Async void in C++ WinRT

Tags: asynchronous, c++-winrt

I want to call non-blocking code in the [`void Page::OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs const&)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom?view=winrt-22000) method in C++/WinRT.

In C#, I could simply use `async void` as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18459893/7571171), but as far as I understand, asynchronous methods need to return `IAsyncAction` (or one of the other interfaces) in order for me to be able to use `co_await` etc.

Does anybody know a way to call asynchronous methods in the aforementioned `OnNavigatingFrom` method or do I have to resort to calling them synchronously (using `.get()` I believe)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept, where

> you have a task that can be done concurrently with other work, and you don't need to wait for that task to complete (no other work depends on it), nor do you need it to return a value

is frequently referred to as [*"fire and forget"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#fire-and-forget). C++/WinRT provides the [`fire_and_forget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/fire-and-forget) struct that can be used as a return type in those situations. To use it you need to change the declaration from

```cpp
void Page::OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs const&)
```

to

```cpp
winrt::fire_and_forget Page::OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs)
```

This allows you (or the framework) to call `OnNavigatingFrom` without `co_await`'ing it. The implementation is free to `co_await` or `co_return` at any point.

As with any co-routine, make sure to **not** accept a (const) reference. It will get invalidated at the first suspension point, and chaos ensues in due time. Pass-by-value disarms this C++ foot gun reliably.